# Using Lagrange multiplier in Euler-Lagrange Equation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I think I am doing something wrong when combining **Lagrange multiplier** and **Euler-Lagrange equation**.

I need to maximize a functional of the form:
$$
\int\!dx~{L(x, G, \dot{G})}~~~~~\text{where } L(a, b, c) = bc - ac,
$$
provided that:
$$
C = \int\!dx~{K(x, G, \dot{G})}~~~~~\text{where } K(a, b, c) = v(a) \times c,
$$
where $v$ itself is a fixed function. Boundary conditions $G(-b)=0$ and $G(b)=1$ are assumed.
Applying the Lagrange multiplier method reduces the problem to maximizing $\int\!dx~({L - \lambda K})$, where $\lambda$ is **constant**.

Euler-Lagrange equation states that the functional's maximizer must satisfies:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial b}(L-\lambda K) = \frac{d}{dx}[\frac{\partial}{\partial c}(L-\lambda K)].
$$
This gives:
$$
\dot{G} = \frac{d}{dx}[G - x - \lambda v(x)] = \dot{G}-1-\lambda \dot{v}\\
\Longrightarrow \lambda = -\frac{1}{\dot{v}}
$$
Which suffers from two problems:

1. All the information about $G$ is lost! I can deduce literally nothing about it.
2. The final result contradicts the assumption of constant $\lambda$.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes it does! I am not sure if it makes any differences but it assumes G(-b)=0 and G(b) = 1. And about maximum/minimum the solution is still the same as above; the functional gradient must be zero at the extremum (i.e Euler-Lagrange equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Dirichlet boundary conditions $G(-b)=0$ and $G(b)=1$ we can remove total derivative terms. The new functional simplifies to 
$$ \int_{-b}^b\! dx~G(x)$$
and the new constraint simplifies to
$$ -\int_{-b}^b\! dx~\dot{v}(x)G(x)~=~\tilde{C}~=~\text{some const}.$$
OP correctly finds that the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation becomes
$$ 1+\lambda\dot{v}~=~0. $$
There are several cases:

1. *Case $\dot{v}~=~0$ and $\tilde{C}~=~0$:* Constraint is automatically satisfied. Then the functional is unbounded from below and from above.
2. *Case $\dot{v}~=~0$ and $\tilde{C}~\neq~0$:* Constraint is never satisfied.
3. *Case $\dot{v}~=~\text{const}~\neq~0$:* Functional takes same value $-\tilde{C}/\dot{v}$ for all configurations $G$ that satisfy constraint.
4. *Case $\dot{v}$ non-constant:* EL equation is impossible to satisfy. Assume for simplicity that $\dot{v}$ is continuous. Then the functional is unbounded from below and from above.